MC1000 Unknown build error, 'Could not find type 'System.Resources.NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute' in assembly \v4.8\Facades\System.Runtime.dll
My project was originally targeting.NETFramework 4.8 and now I am trying to add net8.0 support as well, now after updating all dependent projects it suddenly throwing this compile time error   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\targets\Microsoft.WinFX.targets(211,9): error MC1000: Unknown build error, 'Could not find type 'System.Resources.NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute' in assembly 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\Facades\System.Runtime.dll'.'
How can i resolve this issue?
